# How to cover wrapper class variables in Apex test class?

Tags: apex, code-coverage

I am using a wrapper class (inner class) as below,

```
public without sharing class wmp_ctrl_NotificationHeader {

// other methods 
// 

 public class NotificationsWrapper{
        @AuraEnabled
        public List<Alerts__c> allNotifications; 
        @AuraEnabled
        public Integer unreadAlertSize;
    }
}
```

How can i cover test coverage for the wrapper class which has only these varibles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can i cover test coverage for the wrapper class which has only these varibles?

You can't. Variable declarations outside a method cannot be covered, and do not count for, or against, code coverage requirements. A class with no coverable lines will show coverage as 0% or NaN% (in DX), but will still successfully deploy.

Comment: What a relief to hear!